# Should any domain object, not be serializable?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, serialization, c#-3.0

Is there a way to just tell the compiler, that I want my objects to be serializable by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty much every serialization engine is going to want to know that your objects are suitable. This can take the form of:

- `[Serializable]`/`ISerializable` (`BinaryFormatter`,`SoapFormatter`)
- `[Serializable]`/`IXmlSerializable` (and `public`) (`XmlSerializer`)
- `[DataContract]`/`[MessageContract]` (or most of the above) (`DataContractSerializer` and variants)

AFAIK, there is no way of avoiding this step.

Comment: can you explain a scenario when you wouldn't mark an object serializable?

Comment: @DevelopingChris - when that isn't a requirement, so hasn't been tested properly.

Answer (score 1):

No, you need to decorate the objects with the Serializable attribute. FYI all objects are Xml Serializable by default. The Xml Serializer doesn't require the attribute.

I'm not sure about DataContracts but last I checked you needed to decorate them as well.