# Why do transfer objects need to implement Serializable?

Tags: java, serialization, data-transfer-objects

I realized today that I have blindly just followed this requirement for years without ever really asking why.  Today, I ran across a NotSerializableException with a model object I created from scratch and I realized enough is enough.

I was told this was because of session replication between load-balanced servers, but I know I've seen other objects at session scope that do not implement Serializable.  Is this the real reason?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is the real reason. If it will actually matter in practice depends entirely on if the web server or application server will in fact serialize the object (or validate that it is serializable, but realistically the only way to do that is to actually serialize it).

Most application servers have the option (at least) of not being strict about it. If you don't use load balanced servers that actually share state, then you might have seen it without a problem.

Comment: Thank you.  Makes sense.  So, any session-scoped object that didn't implement Serializable was either not maintaining state itself or running on load-balanced servers that did not share state?

Comment: An object will fail to serialize regardless of any state it maintains, as long as it doesn't implement Serializable, so if I understand your question correctly, the answer is that any objects put in the session that didn't implement Serializable were in fact not serialized by the container, so you didn't see a problem.

Comment: @Yishai Apologies. I still don't get it. For one session object we get exception and not for other session objects, then what is the diff between those 2 objects ? or how/why they are treated differently? What do you mean by state maintenance of on object here ?

Answer (score 10):

Because in order to be transferred across a wire they need to be serialisable to a form that can be put on the wire.

Like binary, or xml, Json, or simillar

There's more info here... [Should any domain object, not be serializable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/340657/should-any-domain-object-not-be-serializable)

Comment: I don't think you need to implement Serializeble to in order to have XML or JSON marhsalling unmarshalling across a wire.  You need it for binary formats - for example in RMI.  But I think the main reason is because these DTOs are part of an HTTP session and therefore HAVE to be serializable according to the servlet specification.

Answer (score 2):

I think the concept is akin to being asked,
why must solid food be chewed down before being swallowed for digestion.
But of course, the difference is that digested good cannot be in anyway deserialized.

I remember using Sun RPC (nowadays called ONC RPC) which performs XDR encoding
because computer platforms/systems represent their data in their respective forms. For example,
big endian vs small endian.

But the JVM, regardless of machine is big-endian, so endianness should not be a reason.

Data structure in computer memory has pointers and all the elements of an object may not sit on a contiguous memory block. However, when you pass an object thro i/o to another system, you cannot pass the memory distribution of that object.

An Object needs to be serialized before being stored in a database because you do not and cannot wish to replicate the dynamically changing arrangement of system memory.

Our data representation layer on the networks are all bit stream-based. Therefore, when you wish to pass data from one system to another, you have to convert the dimensional data represented in memory to one that can be streamed thro the networks byte by byte. Actually, bit by bit, and which often goes thro compression and security encryption. Compression and encryption routines are oo-structure-blind and bit streams are presumed. Network switches are oo-structure-blind. Network transmission does not even see bits. The bits are encoded into a transmission signal that is often analogue sinusoids and then modulated. These processes do not work on multidimensional/hierarchical schemata of oo-structured data.

I guess you could perform object level obfuscation and encryption, yet you still have to allow the system to convert those to bit streams, by converting them to char streams first.

Marshalling is when the shepherd has a herd of sheep and marshalls them thro a single-sheep bridge over troubled waters. Therefore, a marshaller has to marshall our objects into serial schemata with references written in, so that when the flock of information sheep emerge from the other end of the bridge, we are able to reassemble them back into its hierarchical schemata by the conjugate-demarshaller. In our case, our sheep is not marshalled thro just a bridge but thro narrow and precarious windings and landslides where the network transmission equipment at each turn stores a copy of the marshalled sheep to ensure they are able to resend the copy in case any of the sheep has fallen thro a ravine.

Comment: *digested good cannot be in anyway deserialized* It depends what the food was initially. My dog can do this >:)

Comment: My dog eats serialized food too. ugghh.
A theory exists why a dog sometimes eats serialized food. The reasoning is their intestinal tracts are short so that when a dog eats its own serialized food it is lengthening its digestive tracts by twice. And when it eats food serialized by another mammal like a horse, it is borrowing the digestive system of the horse because it is unable to process grass fibre as effectively as a horse or cow.